# How to implement CRUD operations on Xml file in asp.net in 3 tier architecture

Tags: asp.net, xml

I want to implement all create,edit,delete,update,search operations,and datasource is an xml file.I want to implement it in 3 tier architecture.I have tried a lot but it is giving strange errors everytime.can anyone guide me?Thanks in advance...

Comment: what errors do you receive? Could you please post the code you are getting errors with?

Comment: Sorry for late reply.. I have solved that problems.. Thank you.